# Отложенный запуск программ C#

Tags: c#

Как можно после завершения основной программы запустить файл батник который создался при завершении программы, я сделал через процесс старт и тд, но суть такова что нужна задержка, то есть программа закрывается -> ожидание 1 секунда -> запуск бат файла

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-a-batch-file-cmd

Comment: Покажите нам Ваш код, чтобы мы знали от чего отталкиваться

Comment: В батнике нельзя сделать задержку?